# How to enable CORS in Hunchentoot or Clack, or how to add a specific header?

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

The question says it all. This tutorial: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ says to, at the very least, add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to the server's response.

My app, running Hunchentoot, doesn't return it:

```
<!-- GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/ -->
<!-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK -->
<!-- Date: Fri, 13 Oct 2017 23:26:58 GMT -->
<!-- Server: Hunchentoot 1.2.37 -->
<!-- Keep-Alive: timeout=20 -->
<!-- Connection: Keep-Alive -->
<!-- Transfer-Encoding: chunked -->
<!-- Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 -->
<!-- Request duration: 0.004275s -->
```

I looked at [Hunchentoot's doc](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/) and its [headers.lisp](https://github.com/edicl/hunchentoot/blob/master/headers.lisp) file but couldn't find anything CORS-specific and didn't understand how to simply add a header.

Any help ? Thanks !

---

edit: I'm actually using Lucerne and Clack.

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage lisp-todo
  (:use :cl
        :lucerne)
  (:export :app)
  (:documentation "Main lisp-todo code."))
(in-package :lisp-todo)
```

adding

```
(defun change-headers (headers)
  (setf (lack.response:response-headers *response*) headers))
```

C-c C-c =>

> package lack.response does not exist.

or with Hunchentoot:

```
(setf (hunchentoot:header-out "Access-Control-Allow-Origin") "*")
```

> the variable Hunchentoot:*reply* is unbound.

indeed this variable is defined with `def-unbound`.

---

edit2: trying with Ningle

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage todobackend-ningle
  (:use :cl))
(in-package :todobackend-ningle)

;; blah blah blah.

(defvar *response* nil "") ;; to try the snippet below

(defun change-headers (headers)
  ;; (setf (lack.response:response-headers *response*) headers)) ;; => the value nil is not of type lack.response:response
  (setf (lack.response:response-headers lack.response:response) headers)) ;; => unbound

(defvar *app* (make-instance 'ningle:<app>))

(change-headers '(:access-control-allow-origin "*"))

(setf (ningle:route *app* "/")
      (lambda (params) ;; is that right ?
           (change-headers '(:access-control-allow-origin "*"))
           "Welcome to ningle!"))
```

Comment: According to the documentation the `SETF` of `HEADER-OUT` should work for adding new headers.

Comment: Thanks. Have to try a bit more, now `(setf (hunchentoot:header-out "Access-Control-Allow-Origin") "*")` throws me "The variable HUNCHENTOOT:*REPLY* is unbound." because indeed it is declared with `defvar-unbound` and must be used in the context of a request. But I'm using Clack actually, might as well look over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I use for Clack with Ningle, hopefully it can help you:

```
(defpackage ...
  (:use :cl :ningle))
(in-package ...)

(defun change-headers (headers)
  (setf (lack.response:response-headers *response*) headers))

(defmacro api-route (url method en-tetes &body corps)
  `(setf (ningle:route *app* ,url :method ,method)
     ;; that's why your code doesn't work, you actually have to pass a #'function
     #'(lambda (params)
         (change-headers ,headers)
         ,@corps)))
```

*Note : `*response*` comes from [ningle.context](https://github.com/fukamachi/ningle/blob/master/src/context.lisp), and I'm probably using it wrong, according to the comments in the file.*

This macro can be used to create a route and specify headers, like this:

```
(api-route
   "/"
   :get
   '(:access-control-allow-origin "*")
   "Welcome!")
```

Remember, this is enough for a `GET` request, but for other verbs the browser will first hit `OPTIONS`. You'll have to answer it with at least those headers:

```
  '(:access-control-allow-methods "POST"          ; or any other verb(s)
    :access-control-allow-origin "*"
    :access-control-allow-headers "content-type")
```

<sub>This code comes from a small toy project of mine. You can look at [the rest of it](https://cuisine.picdeballmer.science/PicDeBallmer/aperitif-serveur/src/master/src/aperitif.lisp) if you want, hopefully it can give you ideas. It’s nothing grand, and there probably are better ways to do it, but hey — it works.</sub>

Comment: Are you using Clack directly, or with the help of a framework (like Ningle)?

Comment: indeed, with Lucerne.

Comment: At first sight, `package lack.response` does not exist. I'll update my question to show my project skeleton.

Comment: with `(lack.` I have completion for `lack.util/builder/component/middleware` but not `response` !

Comment: I added a Ningle snippet. Compiling this function works, but using it throws errors.

Comment: I edit my answer *a bit*. That `lack.response` thing is weird, I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the example, much welcome (write a bit about it !). In your answer or in your repo, I don't get where `*response*` comes from. It isn't a Lack symbol. I feel obliged to initialize it but that seems wrong (and doesn't seem to work).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `*response*` *is* a Lack symbol, but I lack (hoho) proof. I'll confirm it tonight!

Comment: `*response*` actually comes from ningle (thank you, oh, SLIME), I added that in a note. And as you can see in my full code, I shamelessy `(:use :ningle)`

Comment: oui oui oui oui oui, I didn't see that, searched in lack and clack but not ningle, didn't occur to me (ningle examples directly call `ningle:…`, now it's working and my header is added. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Nice, glad I could help ;)